# factoring out a header and footer in html

Tags: html, header, footer, partial

I looked at this question:

[Splitting up a html page and loading it through header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535504/splitting-up-a-html-page-and-loading-it-through-header)

But the answers weren't quite what I was looking for.

I'm building a completely static web page with a header (navigation) and footer that go on every page. Is there a way to factor out those pieces of markup and insert them on every page, instead of having them on each page separately?

Comment: Can you use PHP..? If it's completely static, then it's not really possible.

Comment: "completely static" so I guess not.

Comment: I'm totally not versed in PHP... yet. Would this alter performance? First answer on this is pretty good:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249825/avoid-repeating-headers-footers?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-generate the pages with something like Jekyll - gives you static pages pre-generated dynamically.